# Returning image to android app from WCF REST using JSON

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, rest

I am trying to return a complex object from C# to an android app via JSON. The image part is giving me difficulty though as this line is blowing out

```
String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

From what I have read and other resources it seems like EntityUtils.toString() is the wrong method to be doing for large image data, I see a lot of examples using `InputStreamEntity` for sending TO a WCF REST webservice from android but no examples of using this the other way around, to RECEIVE the data and decode it into android object types.

Can anyone tell me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats is the content type response from wcf response if its raw image data you can do something like

```
Bitmap  image =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getEntity().getContent())
```

Comment: Well this is where I'm not really sure on the correct design. I want to return a user profile object, which has a number of string/int/date properties and also contains a profile image. So the response is a JSON serialised object with an embedded image - at the moment the JSON contains a huge strsing of binary data which I can already feel is wrong. Do I stream it instead somehow? My friend has suggested using a CDN and only return a string link to the image URL on the CDN... what is the usual practice for this in android apps as I imagine most apps do this?

Comment: CDN is best way to do it, if the image is small you can encode to string and embed in json. but you have to make sure the clients (mobile apps) can decode them correctly. Its a complete overhead. I would recommend using CDN

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any good websites that give a good introduction and examples of how to use CDN in android?

Comment: using CDN is same  as any other platform because at the end everyone w will be seeing a URL to data. the development effort will be at your server/API side to communicate with CDN and push data

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when the app wants to retrieve an image, my web-service will return a URL string only and the app will then set that as the source for the Image View, pulling the data directly from the CDN. When the app wants to upload/store an image, it will post it to the webservice via a byte array for example, then my web-service will have to interface with the CDN to upload it, receive a URL back and store that URL in my database?

Comment: yes. few recomendations use image library like http://square.github.io/picasso/ it will handle lot of things you might need later. If the images are sensitive I would recommend CDN with url randomization or access key suppot ( I dnt know any :( ) so that someone wont download all your profile images with some script.